# Certificate error on Lumia 630 but not other WP devices

Tags: lumia, certificate

I have a domain set up with SSL/TLS using a StartCom Class 2 certificate. When accessing it from a web browser (mobile or desktop: Firefox, Firefox Mobile for Android, iOS Safari, Chrome or IE11) there is no problem, but when accessing it from a Lumia 630 (WP 8.1) with the standard browser I get:

> "Certificate error [...]" - "We're having trouble with this site's
>   security certificate. It looks like the security certificate wasn't
>   issued by a trusted certificate authority. This can indicate an
>   attempt to fool you or access information that you send to the
>   server."

The interesting thing is that other phones running WP (a Lumia 1520 running the exact same OS version, and a Lumia 920) can access the domain without getting certificate errors. I have tested the web server configuration with SSL Labs (Qualys) and it gives an overall A- rating, saying the certificate is trusted and there are no chain issues.

We have tried a factory reset (and then updating) but the problem remains.

The phone runs Windows Phone 8.1 OS version 8.10.12397.895

Comment: Did you check the time and date settings on the 630? It might be the other devices have it set automatically and the 630 does not and if the date is wrong it can cause the cert not to be trusted - happened to me more than handful of times.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem was incorrect date settings on the phone. Although it was set to update date/time automatically it hadn't (it has been connected to a wifi network), so the date was set to 24th of May while the certificate of the site it was trying to reach was created at a later date.

Thanks to TomEus for asking the right question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a very common issue with some of the Lumia phones that don't have the date/time set to auto by default